# error: ‘make_reverse_iterator’ is not a member of ‘std’

Tags: c++, g++, c++14

I'm trying to compile a c++ program which uses std::make_reverse_iterator, but I get the title error. The [reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/make_reverse_iterator) says that the function is indeed supported since c++14, so I added the flag -std=c++14, but still no dice. I've been digging around for a while and can't figure out why this is happening. Any ideas? My compiler version is g++ 4.9.2

Here's a simple program (taken from the above [ref](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/make_reverse_iterator)), the commands used to compile it, and the program's output.

test.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

int main() {
    auto v = std::vector<int>{ 1, 3, 10, 8, 22 };

    std::sort(v.begin(), v.end());
    std::copy(v.begin(), v.end(), std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, ", "));

    std::cout << '\n';

    std::copy(
        std::make_reverse_iterator(v.end()), 
        std::make_reverse_iterator(v.begin()),
        std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, ", "));
}
```

Compiler:

```
g++ -std=c++14 test.cpp -o test
```

Output:

```
test.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:

test.cpp:15:9: error: ‘make_reverse_iterator’ is not a member of ‘std’
         std::make_reverse_iterator(v.end()), 
         ^

test.cpp:16:9: error: ‘make_reverse_iterator’ is not a member of ‘std’
         std::make_reverse_iterator(v.begin()),
```

Comment: What compiler version? I tried a few versions and your code compiles for me.

Comment: @Barry The compiler version is g++ 4.9.2. Updated in the description.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`make_reverse_iterator()` was added as a result of [LWG 2285](https://cplusplus.github.io/LWG/issue2285) and wasn't added to libsdtc++ until [December 2014](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/commit/9f97ef11261291fd99bc840888b76d1bae0c9015). It's in 5.1 release, and everything there. 4.9.2 was just too early to have it. So if possible, just upgrade.

If not possible, this is something that you can add yourself by just copying the [cppreference implementation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/make_reverse_iterator):

```
template< class Iterator >
std::reverse_iterator<Iterator> make_reverse_iterator(Iterator i)
{
    return std::reverse_iterator<Iterator>(i);
}
```